# How to use sprintf instead of hardcoded values

Tags: c, printf

I am developing a firewall for Linux as my project.  I am able to capture packets and to block them.  I am using IPTABLES.

How can I use variables with sprintf instead of hardcoded values?

```
sprintf(comm, "iptables -A INPUT -s $str -j DROP")
// inplace of:
sprintf(comm, "iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.43 -j DROP")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf(comm, "iptables -A INPUT -s %s -j DROP", "192.168.0.43");
// also:
char ipaddress[] = "192.168.0.43";
sprintf(comm, "iptables -A INPUT -s %s -j DROP", ipaddress);
```

Read more in [man sprintf](http://google.com/search?q=man+sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

It works just like regular `printf()`. Same format strings are accepted. However, be careful to avoid overflowing the string buffer. In that sense, `snprintf()` will be MUCH more acceptable than `sprintf()`.

Comment: thanks but it gives  an error of incompatible types
nw wht to do??? 
actually i want to use iptables commands in my c program
its working for static ipaddress but i want to do that for dynamically

Comment: What exactly does the error say? Are you following the `snprintf()` documentation?

Comment: @astha: It sounds like you need to learn about general string manipulation in C, which is a stumbling block for many new programmers.